# Wait for promise to be resolved from React.Context, then render button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, promise, es6-promise

I have a function that fires when a user signs into the app.

```
signin: (email, password, setErrors, setUser, setUserIdToken) => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(res => {
        const user = res.user
        const isVerified = user.emailVerified
        firebase
          .auth()
          .currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
          .then(idTokenResult => {
            setUserIdToken(idTokenResult)
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error))

        setUser(user)
        const db = firebase.firestore()
        if (isVerified) {
          db.collection('/users')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .update({ isVerified: true })
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setErrors(prev => [...prev, err.message])
      })
  },
```

I have another component that uses the `user` and `userIdToken` from the signIn method.

```
const Home = () => {
  const { handleSignout, user, userIdToken } = useContext(firebaseAuth)
  const { emailVerified, email } = user
  const { claims } = userIdToken

  return (
    <div>
      Home page component
      <SurveyResults />
      {emailVerified && email.endsWith('xxx') && !claims.admin ? (
        <button type="button">hi</button>
      ) : null}
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleSignout}>
        sign out
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I don't have access to the properties of `userIdToken` immediatly when Home renders, as I am still waiting for the promise to resolve..But I also need to check the props of userIdToken to render a button. I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: Is the user being redirected from a sign in page to a home page? Can add a conditional based on the user id to render either a loader or home component.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that code. Yes it is. So reckon use hooks to check if `userIdToken` is null? render `<Loader />` or `<Home />`?

Comment: Yes, in the parent component of Home; you can also render Home itself and conditionally render a loader vs the buttons instead.